# Obtain Simulink Object Handle (or path) from slxmlcomp results?

Tags: matlab, comparison, simulink, handle

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am working with versioning/differences between versions of models, and I am wondering if it is possible to get either the handle of the actual block (or the full path to search for the block using find_system) from the results of the xml comparison done using slxmlcomp in Simulink?

Essentially, I use the comparison function (slxmlcomp) to obtain the list of differences, which returns a list of Nodes, and I want to be able to interact with the model elements using a small program. However, the only properties I have access to as a result of the comparison are as follows (see example):

```
cur = 
Node with properties:
    Children: []
      Edited: 1
        Name: 'Comparison1'
  Parameters: [1x1 struct]
      Parent: [1x1 xmlcomp.Node]
     Partner: [1x1 xmlcomp.Node]
```

I have tried reconstructing the paths by adding the parents all the way up, but here the 'parent' is in the tree of differences, not the actual model elements, so I am at a loss.

Help?